# Error setting up algolia with firebase

Tags: node.js, firebase, algolia

Hello I am trying to setup algolia to work with my firebase database here and I am having a little trouble. i followed this guide step by step.

https://www.algolia.com/doc/tutorials/indexing/3rd-party-service/firebase-algolia/

However I am still getting this error when I try to run it

```
'Warning, FIREBASE_CONFIG environment variable is missing. Initializing firebase-admin will fail and then I comment out this line.'
```

I am not sure what is wrong with my code I follewed everything but I am still running into problems. I have included some of the code from my index.js to see if anyone can see anything I did wrong.

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const algoliasearch = require('algoliasearch');
const dotenv = require('dotenv');
const firebase = require('firebase');
// The Firebase Admin SDK to access the Firebase Realtime Database.
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);

// load values from the .env file in this directory into process.env
dotenv.load();


 // Initialize Firebase
 var config = {
    apiKey: "AIzaSyA25OPWS1ign1vKkg7_MFo5SwtqSBezpoo",
    authDomain: "eventful-3d558.firebaseapp.com",
    databaseURL: process.env.FIREBASE_DATABASE_URL,
    projectId: "eventful-3d558",
    storageBucket: "eventful-3d558.appspot.com",
    messagingSenderId: "323022069474"
  };

  firebase.initializeApp(config);

  const database = firebase.database();

// configure algolia
const algolia = algoliasearch(
    process.env.ALGOLIA_APP_ID,
    process.env.ALGOLIA_API_KEY
  );

  const index = algolia.initIndex(process.env.ALGOLIA_INDEX_NAME);


  // Get all contacts from Firebase
database.ref('/events').once('value', event => {

    // Build an array of all records to push to Algolia
    const records = [];
    event.forEach(event => {

      // get the key and data from the snapshot
      const childKey = event.key;
      const childData = event.val();
      // We set the Algolia objectID as the Firebase .key
      childData.objectID = childKey;
      // Add object for indexing
      records.push(childData);
    });

    // Add or update new objects
    index
      .saveObjects(records)
      .then(() => {
        console.log('records are', records);

        console.log('Events imported into Algolia');
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.error('Error when importing events into Algolia', error);
        process.exit(1);
      });
  });
```

Comment: It seems that you're using a mix of the Admin SDK and client Node.js SDKs. I can't say for sure, but the error indicates that the Admin SDK cannot initialize because it's not finding functions.config().firebase. How did you set up Cloud Functions?

Comment: i set them up similar to how the docs say   https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/write-firebase-functions  @JenPerson